# Appcelerator - Images missing from Android App Store package

Tags: android, package, appcelerator, android-image

- When I preview ('Run') my app to a connected Android Device all the
  images work as expected.
- If I dig out the APK from the build > android > bin folder and install it on a device, all images work as expected.

However:

- If I 'Package' for the 'Android App Store' then install the resulting APK on a phone - some of the images are missing.

Is this simply because I am not installing the APK via the app store or is something else going on please!?

Answer (score 0):

I am making all the Noob errors at the moment. This time the issue was to do with image paths.

An image path of

"images/brake-fluid.jpg"

will work on iOS and within the dev environment on Android... but really should be

"/images/brake-fluid.jpg"

to work on the exported Android builds too (note initial forward slash).